# How to set limit getstr by character?

Tags: php, json, curl

As I've been taught here, don't ever cut it off or mess with strings. decode the JSON and extract the relevant property

If you response is like that:

```
\"request_time":"2021-07-11 04:52:07\",\"elapsed_return_time_milliseconds\":26.65,\"access_ip\":null,\"error\":null,\"amount_sent\":1}
```

Means that you need decode with

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
```

This is my updated code to get values, where $inicio contains the JSON response:

```
    $inicio = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($inicio, true);
$gettime = $json['header']['request_time'];

                echo json_encode(array("status" => 1, "msg" => "Error $number - Empty Response"));
            }else{
               echo json_encode(array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Ok $Number - $reqtime Response"));
            }
```

The output now is:

```
Ok 123456 - $2021-07-11 04:52:07 Response
```

So if I need get request_time value from this response:

```
 "header": {
    "api_version": "3.0.0",
    "type_connection": 1,
    "user": "",
    "request_time": "2021-07-11 05:46:24",
    "elapsed_return_time_milliseconds": 28.34,
    "access_ip": null,
    "error": null,
    "amount_sent": 1
  },
```

I can use this:

```
$gettime = $json['header']['request_time'];
```

Thank you very much!
Please formulate the answer so I can mark as correctly

Comment: Don't cut it off or mess with strings. It looks like JSON so decode the JSON and extract the relevant property

Comment: Could you show me more with an short example? Please formulate an answer

Comment: Hang on, perhaps I misunderstood a little bit, are you saying it's a raw string before you json_encode it? It wasn't very clear what value you are starting off with? What is the original value of `$inicio`?

Comment: The value of `$inicio` is this json response `\"request_time":"2021-07-11 04:52:07\",\"elapsed_return_time_milliseconds\":26.65,\"access_ip\":null,\"error\":null,\"amount_sent\":1}`

I need print only request_time and if `$reqtime` is empty send as json_encode with status 1, else if it's empty send as json_encode with status 0

Comment: Inside `echo json_encode(array(` I need print the response previously stored in string `$reqtime` (it already occours but it print entire response and I need cutoff unecessary part, As you said I should decode JSON and extract but don't figure out how to do

Comment: Please add the full json object that you get to your question. The one you posted (My json response) seems to be truncated.

Comment: `this json response`... But what you've shown us isn't valid JSON. Did you omit part of it?

Comment: Updated the question with full response, I shorten it because it was too big.
About not being a JSON valid response maybe it was because this bars? \ \

If was it that you mean, I don't know why but the response appears like this with a lot \ \ \  when I print using the variable `$reqtime`

Accessing the response by URL, I get the regular response (the same fully response that I've updated on question)

Thank you all guys in advance
It's really cool receive multiple supports like that

Comment: then you need to decode the JSON, extract the date value to a variable and then re-use it in your later output. Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: P.s. The backslashes ( \ ) were added by you when you tried to encode something to json which was contained double quotes to begin with.

Comment: @ADyson already tried a similar solution but it not worked when I try to print the response of $reqtime variable inside  echo json_encode(array(

Do you know if is possible decode the JSON and print the variable value inside an encode?

Comment: I will read this topic and try it again, probably I've missed something
Really appreciate your help @ADyson Thank you!

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible to do what you described. Once you've decoded it it's just a PHP variable like any other. Maybe show us exactly what you tried already

Comment: I tried to get value of request_time from response like that:

`$json = json_decode($inicio, true);
$gettime = $json[0]['header']['request_time'];`

the request_time value is inside header array, is this code correct ?
If yes, I will update my question and you can formulate a answer since my problem must be solved decoding json

but when I try print $gettime I get an empty value

Comment: `is this code correct `... No I don't think so because the original JSON is an object not an array so there won't be a [0] index. You can check the structure with var_dump

Comment: Just try `$json['header']['request_time'];` directly

Comment: Oh my god, it worked!! I was trying with [0] that was the problem...
I've updated my question, can you formalize the answer? so we done here

after that, i believe i can do it alone i will try to learn more and more really thank you for your patience

Comment: Hello again @ADyson, I already finish all variables, is just pretty print and follow copying variables. Thanks to you. Just formulate a answer with `$json['header']['request_time'];`